# Winforms: Capture part of PDF image to OCR

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, screenshot

This is a C# winforms question.

The process I am trying to achieve is the following:

1. Using AxAcroPDFLib I'm loading a pdf file to the form
2. I want the user to be able to specify a square on that PDF and create a bmp from it
3. That bmp will then be loaded to a OCR to become text

**What is my issue:**

Step 1 and 3 are easy to do, the problem is how to allow the user to draw a square on top of the AxAcroPDFLib for a screenshot.

I already got different ways to draw squares on native winform components, but AxAcroPDFLib does not support mouse down, up, move, etc and paint events.

There is the option to convert the PDF to bitmap and display it on a picturebox and deal with events for drawing the square. Problem with that approach is that my PDF's are usually more than two pages, and I would like to avoid the conversion pdf to bmp due to changes to image quality that will impact on OCR.

I came to think that maybe something that works as the windows snippingtool would do the the job. My application would get the screenshot, temporarily save the image on disk (must be a file for OCR), I would then pass it to the OCR and done. Hard part, I could not think on how to take the screenshot of part of the PDF.

Do anyone here have any suggestion to different components or workarounds to deal with the requirement above? I am using Adobe just because it is simple, but maybe there are other components better suited to handle my requirements? I googled but haven't found any free ones, trying to avoid paid options.

Thanks

Comment: "_I would like to avoid the conversion pdf to bmp due to changes to image quality that will impact on OCR_" Convert it to something other than bmp that has higher quality? (I use bmp for something else btw and it is fine and clear, but huge in size)

Comment: Considering that as a possible workaround, gif/png in order to save size, but honestly never had to do it before, so I can't assume the process is as simple as and will maintain the dpi. Nonetheless I would like to exhaust the main option in order to skip handling conversion of pdf's with multiple pages and to not lose work I've done so far that would be affected by this change. No big deal (I think), but still some re-work and learn new ways to do things can be handful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point in this process, the PDF is going to have to be rasterized in order to be passed to the OCR, so I don't totally understand your objection to converting it to a bitmap.  If you're okay with Snipping Tool's behavior, then you must be OK with the quality of the PDF control's PDF->screen rasterization.  If that resolution is acceptable, why not just capture the control's content to a `Bitmap` and let the user draw the selection marquee over that `Bitmap`?

Here is code I'm using to capture a control's contents to a `Bitmap` in Windows Forms.  One caveat is that this is really a screen capture, so any windows or controls that overlap the control's visible area will be captured in the image.

```
using (Bitmap b = new Bitmap(width, height))
{
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
    {
        Point p1 = myControl.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
        g.CopyFromScreen(p1.X, p1.Y, 0, 0, size);
    }
    // do stuff here with your Bitmap
}
```

Comment: The PDF I have usually have a very high quality. When zooming in/out the pixels don't "explode". True that rasterization will brake that, but changes are that the user will not zoom out to the point the captured image cannot be OCR'ed. As for the content, the idea is to allow the user to select "small" pieces/part of the pdf to be recognized by the OCR. It can be just a line, or a portion of "text". Thus it is not productive (for this solution) to convert the whole control content. Other than that, your code would fit in nice if I had mouse events available.

Comment: @EstevaoSantiago, the memory and processing time required to capture the portion of the document visible in the control at any time is negligible on modern computers.  What prevents you from capturing the control when the user indicates he/she would like to select some of it and temporarily overlaying the captured image over the control with a `PictureBox`, which *does* have mouse events available?

Comment: Great point, and quick answer is: nothing... I haven't considered that approach. I was limited to the option of working on a solution on the adobe component only. Activating an overlay with a bitmap of the current pdf page could indeed be a solution... and allows me to add some other features. Not the original idea, but a valid workaround. I will play it out with your code and let you know if its a nice solution to my question :)

Comment: some clarification if you may? the Bitmap B I set the size of the image I am to create, correct? As for the Point P1, the X, Y coordinates there, Am I to set them to something? The position of my control for instance? On g.CopytFromScreen. P1X and Y are obtained from the above line. What about the other two 0? What am I to use as int.destination X & Y? The last argument size, is the size of the image I am about to create (800x600, 1024x900, etc), correct? 
Im getting a system.argument.exception in drawing.dll: Parameter not valid.

Comment: Forget all the clarification I asked above, checked the MSDN docs instead to clarify doubts. Although the exception being throw is related to using picturebox1.image = b (b is from your bitmap). Could not find the reason why. Can you offer any advice?

Comment: Not quite sure why you got an error setting the image on the `PictureBox`, but you probably don't want the `using(...)` in your code if you want the `Bitmap` to hang around.  In my case I was just saving out the `Bitmap`, so it was okay to dispose it immediately after that.